# Accept array and non-array value in setter - solving different accessor types

Tags: typescript

My Angular component has an input which generally operates on an array of strings:

```
@Input() names: string[]

<my-comp [names]="['Adam', 'Betty']"></my-comp>
```

But I want to provide an alternate syntax so that the user can provide a single value without having to type brackets:

```
<my-comp names="Adam"></my-comp>
```

And process it in the setter like so:

```
private _names: string[];
@Input() set names(value: string[] | string) {
  this._names = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
}
get names(): string[] {
  return this._names;
}
```

This however brings up TSLint error TS2380 complaining that the accessors should have same type.

My question is: is there a nice TS way of solving such a case?

Comment: the easiest is just giving a getter / setter different names, e.g. `get namesArray` or `@Input('names') set namesMixed`

Comment: @smnbbrv So true! I have always copied same pattern. I wonder if that can always work≠be a solution, but for now it works. Why don't you make it an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, TypeScript thinks of property accessors as of real property and is quite strict with that.

The easiest is just giving a getter / setter different names, e.g.

```
private _names: string[];

@Input() set names(value: string[] | string) {
  this._names = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
}

get namesArray(): string[] {
  return this._names;
}
```

or, in this particular case, Angular allows to map it to the real input name

```
names: string[];

@Input('names') set namesMixed(value: string[] | string) {
  this.names = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
}
```

so you don't even need the private property.